# Parsing date like twitter

Tags: javascript

I've made a little forum and
I want parse the date on newest posts like twitter, you know "posted 40 minutes ago ","posted 1 hour ago"... 
What's the best way ?
Thanx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [Pretty date in JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/), by John Resig.

For example:

```
prettyDate("2008-01-28T20:24:17Z") // => "2 hours ago"
prettyDate("2008-01-27T22:24:17Z") // => "Yesterday"
prettyDate("2008-01-26T22:24:17Z") // => "2 days ago"
prettyDate("2008-01-14T22:24:17Z") // => "2 weeks ago"
prettyDate("2007-12-15T22:24:17Z") // => undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking in Ruby check that out:

```
def created_at_pretty 
  _now = Time.now
  dif = (_now - self.created_at).to_i 

  if dif < 60
    dif = "#{dif} seconds"
  elsif dif > 59 && dif < 120 
    dif = "1 minute"
  elsif dif > 119 && dif < 3600
    dif =  "#{dif/60} minutes"
  elsif dif > 3599 && dif < 7200
    dif = "1 hour"
  elsif dif > 7199 && dif < 86400
    dif =  "#{dif/60/60} hours"
  elsif dif > 86399 && dif < 172800
    dif = "1 day"
  elsif dif > 172799 && dif < 5184000
    dif =  "#{dif/60/60/24} days"
  elsif dif > 5183999 && dif < 10368000
    dif = "1 month"
  elsif dif > 10367999 && dif < 62208000
    dif =  "#{dif/60/60/24/30/12} months"
  elsif dif > 62207999 && dif < 124416000
    dif = "1 year"
  elsif dif > 124415999
    dif =  "#{dif/60/60/24/30/12/12} years"
  end  
  "#{dif} ago"
```

end

Comment: Wanna translate that into Javascript?